# Earth Engine - how to access an image added to Map from inside a function

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a simple UI that allows the user to select an image from a collection, and loads it to the map.

The user then can select a polygon from a list, and a `.reduceRegion()` using that geometry is to be done on the chosen image.

However, as the variable `myImage` is created inside a function called by the select box, it can't be accessed by the next select box to choose the polygon.

What change to I need to make so that the variable is accessible from the next function?

Full script link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/9346c185b24619647e10df0018ce2213

```
// Create imageSelect
var imageSelect = ui.Select(getImageIds(myCollection),"Select an image")

// Create polySelect
var polySelect = ui.Select(["geometry1","geometry2"])

print(imageSelect);
print(polySelect);

var loadImage = function(){
  var imageID = imageSelect.getValue()
  var myImage = ee.Image(myCollection.filterMetadata("system:id","equals",imageID).first())
  //print(myImage)
  Map.addLayer(myImage.select("B3"))

}

var reduceTheRegion = function(){
  var poly = polySelect.getValue()
  var myFeature = geomCollection.filterMetadata("name","equals",poly)
  Map.addLayer(myFeature,{color:"red"},poly)
  var polyMean = myImage.select("B3").reduceRegion({
                reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                geometry: myFeature.geometry()

  })
  print(polyMean)
}

imageSelect.onChange(loadImage)

polySelect.onChange(reduceTheRegion)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just similar as you retrieve the image from the imageSelect function, you can get the image inside the polySelect function. Note that I changed the Map.addLayer to Map.Layers.set(), so the image is overwritten and not added,which is probably what you want making this kind of UI tools.

```
var reduceTheRegion = function(){
  var poly = polySelect.getValue();
  var myFeature = geomCollection.filterMetadata("name","equals",poly);
  // retrieve the image from the selected value
  var myImage = myCollection.filterMetadata("system:id","equals",imageSelect.getValue()).first()
  
  var polyMean = myImage.select("B3").reduceRegion({
                reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                geometry: myFeature.geometry()
  
  })
  Map.layers().set(1, ui.Map.Layer(myFeature,{color:"red"},poly))
  print(polyMean)
}
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a9c369f973f2326621602e401a2f53c6)

Comment: While I was thinking of a possible solution, one of them was to place in a hidden label the value of the image...  and then retrieve it from the reduceTheRegion function.  It never occurred to me to do as you did, get the value from the select...  The Forest for the Trees...  And the nifty solution in code2, to return the image and use it again to get the image is one that I will have to keep for future reference.   Thanks!

Comment: @Kuik did you deactivate the links of alternative options?

Comment: They are apparently broken. I removed them from the post.